# Как создать указатель на голову в односвязном списке в си?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct t_list{
        int hour;
        int minute;
        struct t_list *next;
}t_list;
t_list *create_node(int set_hour, int set_minute){
    t_list *node=(t_list *)malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    node->hour=set_hour;
    node->minute=set_minute;
    node->next=NULL;
    return node;
}
void push_front(t_list **list, int set_hour,int set_minute){
    t_list *new_element=create_node(set_hour, set_minute);
    new_element -> next = *list;
    *list=new_element;
}
```

Как добавить указатель на голову списка?

Comment: Непонятно, в чем вопрос? Вы же его и возвращаете из своих функций? Вернее, из первой возвращаете, во второй — храните в `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. вы функцией `push_front` добавляете элемент в начало списка, то первый параметр у вас всегда будет указателем на голову

```c
void push_front(t_list **list, int set_hour,int set_minute){
    t_list *new_element=create_node(set_hour, set_minute);
    new_element -> next = *list;
    *list=new_element;
}

t_list *head = NULL;
push_front(&head, 1, 2);
push_front(&head, 3, 4);
push_front(&head, 5, 6);
```